# how use multiple outgoing interfaces haproxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

Is there a way to implement the following scenario (art of reverse proxy) :

Need a backend interface let say eth0 to listen for incoming HTTP/HTTPS traffic  and then forward all incoming HTTP/HTTPS traffic to eth1 till eth8. by using  round robin load balancing ?